# Test for git direct descendant

Tags: git, merge, push, descendant

Anyone know how to test if mybranch-working, a local branch, is a direct descendant of an origin/staging branch.  In other words, I would like to test if another developer has merged there changes into origin/staging since I last merged from origin/staging into mybranch-working.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the 'double-dot' syntax:

```
git log mybranch-working..origin/staging
```

This shows you all commits that are in `origin/staging` but are not in `mybranch-working`.

This command is a shorthand for:

```
git log ^mybranch-working origin/staging
```

In fact you can specify more than two references. An alternative to `^` is `--not`:

```
git log master ^topicA --not topicB
```

Comment: Thanks.  I think I like "git whatchanged mybranch-working..origin/staging" a bit better.